# how to calculate user engagement in bigquery for each user based on their first and latest interaction over the last 52 weeks

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am a beginner with bigquery and I am trying to calculate user engagement for cohort analysis based on their first interaction to the last interaction over a time period of 52 weeks. The first and last interaction will be different for each user.

Currently I have got this working over few weeks, but the query is getting really verbose. So if I had to do it over 52 weeks, the query would be really unmanageable.

```
    WITH base_dataset AS (
  SELECT 
    user, 
    event_timestamp, 
    element,
    event_type
  FROM 
    `events`
), calculate_user_integration_range AS (
  SELECT 
    user, 
    MIN(event_timestamp) AS first_seen_timestamp,
    MAX(event_timestamp) AS last_seen_timestamp 
  FROM 
    base_dataset
  group by 
    user
), combine_range_with_base_dataset AS (
  SELECT 
    base_dataset.user, 
    event_timestamp,
    element,
    calculate_user_integration_range.first_seen_timestamp,
    calculate_user_integration_range.last_seen_timestamp
  FROM 
    base_dataset
  FULL OUTER JOIN calculate_user_integration_range ON calculate_user_integration_range.user = base_dataset.user
), 

week_1 as (
  select 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.user, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp, 
    DATE_DIFF(combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp,combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, day) as total_days,
    count(*) as count_week_1,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.element, 
  from 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset 
  where 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.event_timestamp > TIMESTAMP_ADD(combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL 0 DAY) 
    AND combine_range_with_base_dataset.event_timestamp <= TIMESTAMP_ADD(combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
  group by 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.user, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.element, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp
), 
week_2 as (
  select 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.user, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp, 
    DATE_DIFF(combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp,combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, day) as total_days,
    count(*) as count_week_2,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.element, 
  from 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset 
  where 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.event_timestamp > TIMESTAMP_ADD(combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
    AND combine_range_with_base_dataset.event_timestamp <= TIMESTAMP_ADD(combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
  group by 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.user, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.element, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp
), 
week_3 as (
  select 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.user, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp, 
    DATE_DIFF(combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp,combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, day) as total_days,
    count(*) as count_week_3,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.element, 
  from 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset 
  where 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.event_timestamp > TIMESTAMP_ADD(combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
    AND combine_range_with_base_dataset.event_timestamp <= TIMESTAMP_ADD(combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL 21 DAY) 
  group by 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.user, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.element, 
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.first_seen_timestamp,
    combine_range_with_base_dataset.last_seen_timestamp
)
select
  COALESCE(week_1.user, week_2.user, week_3.user) user,
  COALESCE(week_1.first_seen_timestamp, week_2.first_seen_timestamp, week_3.first_seen_timestamp) first_seen,
  COALESCE(week_1.last_seen_timestamp, week_2.last_seen_timestamp, week_3.last_seen_timestamp) last_seen,
  COALESCE(week_1.total_days, week_2.total_days, week_3.total_days) total_days,
  COALESCE(week_1.element, week_2.element, week_3.element) element,
  IFNULL(count_1, 0) as count_1, 
  IFNULL(count_week_1, 0) as count_week_1, 
  IFNULL(count_week_2, 0) as count_week_2, 
  IFNULL(count_week_3, 0) as count_week_3, 
from 
  week_1  
  FULL OUTER JOIN week_2 ON week_1.user = week_2.user AND week_1.element = week_2.element
  FULL OUTER JOIN week_3 ON week_1.user = week_3.user AND week_1.element = week_3.element
```

With this query, I am able to get the output I need as follows

| user | first_seen | last_seen | total_days | element | count_week_1 | count_week_2 | count_week_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-26 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 1 | Page1 | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| user1 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-26 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 1 | Button1 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| user1 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-26 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 1 | Button2 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| user4 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-26 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 1 | Page3 | 1 | 5 | 2 |
| user2 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-27 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 2 | Page1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| user2 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-27 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 2 | Button4 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| user3 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-29 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 4 | Page1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| user3 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-29 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 4 | Button1 | 5 | 0 | 3 |
| user3 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-29 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 4 | Button2 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| user4 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-28 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 3 | Page3 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| user4 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-28 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 3 | Page1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| user4 | 2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000 UTC | 2022-03-28 13:36:14.870000 UTC | 3 | Button4 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

Is there a different way I can do this so that the query is not so verbose?

I have looked into generating the counts using a function but the function declaration keeps giving me declaration errors for variables as the data I need to use defined in `WITH`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'user1' as user, DATETIME '2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000' as event_timestamp, 'Page1' element UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user1' as user, DATETIME '2022-03-26 13:36:14.870000' as event_timestamp, 'Page1' element UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2' as user, DATETIME '2022-03-25 11:28:05.217000' as event_timestamp, 'Page1' element UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user2' as user, DATETIME '2022-04-05 13:36:14.870000' as event_timestamp, 'Page2' element 
)
SELECT user, element, first_seen_timestamp, last_seen_timestamp,
  DATE_DIFF(last_seen_timestamp, first_seen_timestamp, day) AS total_days,
  SUM(is_week_1) as count_week_1,
  SUM(is_week_2) as count_week_2
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN event_timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL  0 DAY) 
          AND event_timestamp <  TIMESTAMP_ADD(first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL  7 DAY)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS is_week_1,
    CASE WHEN event_timestamp >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL  7 DAY) 
          AND event_timestamp <  TIMESTAMP_ADD(first_seen_timestamp, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS is_week_2 
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
      MIN(event_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS first_seen_timestamp,
      MAX(event_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS last_seen_timestamp
    FROM sample_table
  )
)
GROUP BY user, element, first_seen_timestamp, last_seen_timestamp
```

The calculations in brief:

- first/last seen timestamp using WINDOW function to avoid joining tables
- is_week_1 - flag whether event occurred during the first week
- count_week_1 - sum of flags to get total counts per week